# DRBD device temporarily disappearing across different kernel versions?

Tags: kernel, drbd

After upgrading from an old kernel to a new kernel version and booting into the new kernel the DRBD logical device was gone.

Think nothing under `/proc/drbd.`
This is a major problem as I have DRBD running in a cluster, with a heartbeat running between the Primary and Secondary nodes.

After rebooting into the new kernel however, the DRBD device has re-appeared. Has anyone experienced fluctuating behaviour of this sort?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you needed to reboot twice?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? What versions of the drbd-utils and kernel module do you have installed?